# prolem posting data from python urllib2 to elasticsearch http 400 bad request

Tags: python, json, http, elasticsearch, urllib2

i have written a python script that interacts with elastic-search , when i use elasticsearch library , everything works fine , such getting data and posting data , but when i use urllib2 the get works fine but posting data to elastic search results in http error 400 bad request , i have tried many times , changing the json payload , encoding , utf8 , json.dumps , almost all the things , but in every case i get the error http 400 bad request. can anyone help? i have also tried the request library , the get is fine and the post is not giving any error but it still doesnt actually works , it doesnt insert the payload.

Comment: Define 'posting data to elasticsearch'. Have you tried using the provided libraries for Python: `elasticsearch-py` and/or `elasticsearch-dsl`?

Comment: yes , the elasticsearch python library works , but the requirement is that not to use that option , i am trying to use urllib2.

Comment: posting data means , sending data